# No mic activity with setLoopBack set to false - AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

Trying to figure out why setloopback needs to be set to true 
for microphone activity to be detected.

The problem is the echo feedback when using a macbook with a built in mic.

If anyone has some ideas about this let me know.

Right now I'm experimenting with toggling gain, depending on activity to simulate echo reduction. Not optimal though.

@lessfame

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to display microphone activity without sending the audio to the speakers. The echo renders Flash audio recording useless...

Answer (score 13):

I was looking for a similar solution to this one, then I found you that you can apply a sound transform to a microphone to control the volume of the outputted volume of the microphone input.

So it can be done this easily:

```
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
mic.soundTransform = st;
```

I know you asked this question almost a year ago now, but thought I'd put it up for anybody looking for an answer.
Cheers,
Will

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but just came across the problem.

There is a bug with the SPEEX codec as noted here: [Microphone soundTransform and SPEEX codec bug](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/144047)

This bug basically says that using the SPEEX codec ignores the sound transform.  As a work around for this I setup a toggle function to switch the settings for the microphone to display activity before the audio is attached to a NetStream and to work around the bug.

> Note: A Microphone object only dispatches Activity events when your application is monitoring the microphone. Thus, if you do not call setLoopBack( true ), add a listener for sample data events, or attach the microphone to a NetStream object, then no activity events are dispatched. [AS3 Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0c)

Setup the Mic: (m is an instance variable)

```
m = Microphone.getMicrophone();
m.setSilenceLevel(0);
m.gain = 75;
m.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
m.rate = 16;    //rate only applies to NELLYMOSER Codec - but 16 kHz matches SPEEX default setting
m.setLoopBack(true);    //necessary to get activity
m.codec = SoundCodec.NELLYMOSER;    //this is default
m.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);    //mute so you don't get crazy echo!
```

Toggle for 'offline' and 'online' activity monitoring

```
protected function audioMeterToggle(switch:String) {
    if(switch == "offline") {
        m.setLoopBack(true);
        m.soundTransform.volume = 0;
        m.codec = SoundCodec.NELLYMOSER;
    } else {
        m.setLoopBack(false);
        m.soundTransform.volume = 1;
        m.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    }
}
```

Switching codecs helps reduce bandwidth.

Hope this helps save someone some time.